# What is the purpose of the tube connecting to the overflow pipe in my toilet tank?

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, toilet

My dual flush toilet was leaking; this is what the connections looked like before I "fixed" it:

[image]
Notice the ivory-yellow  hose is connected to the blue-plastic fitting on the overflow tube.

In response to my asking my brother how to stop the leak, he told me to remove the hose from the blue-plastic fitting, and let its flow go into the tank. To my amazement this worked; it stopped leaking. But I wonder what the hose is supposed to do there, and what was the effect of our disconnecting it from its original fitting? And, by the way, I have found that if we just plug or pinch the hose, don't let water run out of the hose, everything works well. So what is the role of this hose?

Comment: it feeds water into the bowl after a flush to help rinse while the tank and bowl fills. It sounds like you have bad gaskets/dry-rotted and removing this didn't actually fix anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience with USA model *single* flush toilets, if you would take a pitcher of water and pour it down that vertical tube (called the overflow tube), you would see water going down into the bowl of the toilet, bypassing the flapper valve.

When the toilet refills after being flushed and the flapper valve is closed, most of the water goes into the tank (cistern) but some goes through that plastic hose into the overflow tube and into the bowl. I assume this is to insure that the bowl has enough water to seal the S-drain in the toilet. When the valve shuts off the water flow, this stream of water should stop. If the flow of water out the tube does not stop, then there is a fault in the valve.

If water is continually coming out of this hose, then pulling the hose out of the overflow tube would simply redirect the leak into the tank which would over fill and finally go out the overflow tube. However, if the toilet was used frequently, then the toilet might get flushed before water went out the overflow and in a sense the leak would be stopped.

The one way I can think of that pulling this hose out of the overflow tube could "stop" the leak would be if the extra water in the toilet would cause more compression of the seal in the valve and so actually shut off the water, but this seems improbable.

If I had this situation, I would consider changing the main seal in the valve, but this operation could go wrong and damage the valve.

**EDIT**
If you leave the hose *out* of the overflow tube, you should notice that the bowl has a lower water level in it. If you would decide to just use it that way, you could keep a pitcher of water on hand and as the toilet is refilling (or after),  *gently* add just enough water to the bowl to bring it over the lip to seal out sewer smells. If you add the water too rapidly, then you would start the siphon action which would pull too much water out of the bowl.

If you would plug or pinch the little hose in question, then it will become pressurized something which it is not designed for. Also parts of the flow valve could be improperly pressurized. This might eventually rupture the hose or the valve assembly.

Comment: +1. Put the hose back where it belongs and address the root-cause of the problem.

Comment: Depending on your relationship with your brother, you might want to leave the hose dripping into the tank for a while. Take the time to find out about getting a new seal for the valve and understanding the procedure for installing it. I have found that these plastic toilet fill valves are sometimes difficult to disassemble. Depending on how long this valve has been in service you might want to prepare yourself for replacing the entire valve assembly.

Comment: @JimStewart thank you, I fully understand now